# Select last date and COUNT rows in a JOIN jquery?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I want to select the last inserted date and at the same time I want to select the user-name and count how many times the user-profile is visited.

So I am using this query

```
SELECT v.visitor_date, i.info_name, count(DISTINCT v.visitor_date) AS     counted
FROM profile_visitors v
INNER JOIN profile_info i ON i.info_userId = v.visitor_accountId
ORDER BY v.visitor_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The result of the fiddle is wrong and SHOULD be

2015-07-28 11:05:16 - Testname  - 5

Anyone knows what is wrong with the query?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2814c/1

Comment: i can't access your fiddle - but that might be a glitch at their end?

Comment: Strange, worked for me in chrome, ie and firefox.

Comment: What's the difference between info_id and info_userId?

Comment: Info_id is the primary, however problem is solved, thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you seem to think so! So I guess it must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT  does NOT give you the first or last record of any group, in fact you cannot guarantee which record DISTINCT will display within a group (nor does this matter by the way). So select MAX visitor date.

Try below query

```
SELECT MAX( v.visitor_date ) , i.info_name, COUNT( DISTINCT v.visitor_date ) AS counted FROM profile_visitors v INNER JOIN profile_info i ON i.info_userId = v.visitor_accountId ORDER BY v.visitor_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: After a little modification your query does exactly what I want.   `SELECT MAX(v.visitor_date), i.info_name,  COUNT(DISTINCT v.visitor_date) AS counted
FROM profile_visitors v
LEFT JOIN profile_info i ON i.info_userId = v.visitor_accountId
GROUP BY v.visitor_accountId code`.  Or fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/399f4/1 So much thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try it:

```
SELECT v.visitor_date, 
       i.info_name, 
       COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM profile_visitors v
INNER JOIN profile_info i ON i.info_userId = v.visitor_accountId
GROUP BY v.visitor_accountId
ORDER BY v.visitor_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Still it giving different result. Date should be 28 it giving 27. Check out query in my answer below

Comment: As Santosh Jagtap said, the wrong date is displayed.